# TinyMCE Rich text editor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I've TinyMCE editor to key in Rich text in my MVC app. I'm finding difficulty to add "aria-hidden" attribute to all my button? may i know is there a step to archive it ?

Comment: Are you using Tinymce version 4, 5 or 6?

Comment: I'm using version 4

Comment: I've solved the issue using JavaScript function....  $('.mce-widget').each(function () {
            $(this).attr("aria-hidden", true);
        });